# How to redirect website after submitting google form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I use google form in my website without iframe tag, so I didn't find how to write "thank you" and cancel going to the response page of google form.

This is the html code:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/2/d/e/1FAIpQLSeBJHw1Q6YlwO_0s2OgMhuyQEj4PLvToM1N1G5BEYQRiZlCLQ/formResponse">
                <label for="">It's FREE</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="inputs" id="input1" name="entry.1045366435">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="inputs" id="input2" name="entry.1398681060">
                <textarea id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message" name="entry.403219718"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
            </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
```

What do I need to write in the js file ?
Thank you very much a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the form is submitted or not. The following code is used jQuery.

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert(1); // example code
  // add your code here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/2/d/e/1FAIpQLSeBJHw1Q6YlwO_0s2OgMhuyQEj4PLvToM1N1G5BEYQRiZlCLQ/formResponse">
  <label for="">It's FREE</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="inputs" id="input1" name="entry.1045366435">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="inputs" id="input2" name="entry.1398681060">
  <textarea id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message" name="entry.403219718"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```